# Not able to read JSON data from secure protocol, getting "Access Denied" error with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to read data from one of the JSON feeds URL and i have used $.getJson(), the feed URL is in diff domain but both are on secured protocol, the same is working on http protocol, but not on https. If anybody has faced similar prob or aware what might be the reason. Please share..thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using JSONP? Do you have '?callback=?' in your URL?

Comment: Does the feed server provide "JSON-P" (sometimes called JSON-in-script) feeds? If so, you better use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting the data doesn't override [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you can't read data from a different domain with XHR.

Use JSON-P or a get your server to fetch it on the user's behalf.

Comment: I have used JSON-P also. After adding the callback=? the script started giving java script error

Comment: The nature of the error should tell you the next step you need to take in order to get it working.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue with JSONP thanks for the help